Who first introduced trigonometric substitutions in integral calculus?
I've been researching the history of integral calculus, specifically focusing on the use of trigonometric substitutions. Despite my efforts, it remains unclear who first introduced this technique. Could anyone provide insights or references regarding the earliest documented use of trigonometric substitutions in integration? Any historical context or contributions from specific mathematicians would be greatly appreciated.

Could you please summarized how far back you have traced such substitutions thanks to your efforts? Documenting preliminary research helps avoid duplicated effort.

The default answer to "who first used integration technique XYZ" is: Euler.

@njuffa: Please, see here. It seems Barrow used the "reverse" of what we call today as trig. subs. in the evaluation of the integral of secant function.
